# KeyboardAvoidingView padding bug

Tags: react-native

There is **to little padding** being used by the **KeyboardAvoidingView** of **react-native**. Which results in my **keyboard moving over the inputfield**:
[image]

**My current solution**
I made an attempt to fix this problem using *keyboardVerticalOffset*.
This is the render function of the view from the image, which is using the KeyboardAvoidView:

```
render() {
    return (
      <KeyboardAvoidingView
        behavior="padding"
        key={this.state.keyboardRandomKey}
        keyboardVerticalOffset={50}
      >
        @@ all the other stuff of the design is here @@
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
  }
}
```

**The problem**
This image shows the problem I'm having after implementing the previous shown code. The red arrow is showing the unexpected behavior.
As you can see extra space is being added but it's a grey area. This has to be transparent. Somehow I can't get this to work. I have used keyboardVerticalOffset previously with a minus value on a different project and that worked fine.
[image]

Any ideas are well appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I added a hide & show listener to  keyboard**

```
 componentDidMount() {
    this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      'keyboardDidShow',
      this.keyboardDidShowListener,
    );
  }
```

**I made a state value keyboardOpen and set this to true if the keyboard is open.**

```
keyboardDidShowListener = e => {
    this.setState({
      keyboardOpen: true,
      keyboardHeight: e.endCoordinates.height,
    });
  };
```

**I set the value to false if the keyboard hides**

```
keyboardHideListener = () => {
    this.setState({
      keyboardAvoidingViewKey: new Date().getTime(),
      keyboardOpen: false,
    });
  };
```

**In reacts return i check if the keyboard is open and re-render some elements accordingly with marginBottom: 0**

```
if (this.state.keyboardOpen) {
      return (
        <View style={{ marginBottom: 0 }}>
          <RoundTab title="Sign In" onPress={() => this.signIn()} />
        </View>
      );
```

**Result**
[image]
Also **adding a view** with a certain height **after the TextInput** is an easy fix to add some padding and fix the issue